# angular ui bootstrap typeahead - Before select callback

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, typeahead

Is there anyway to get the value of the angular ui bootstrap typeahead selection before it changes the model?

Thanks alot!

Uri

Comment: Why? This sounds a lot like an XY problem. Also, the answer is almost certainly no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in way to do this with with typeahead, but you can just store the old value in your ng-change

```
<input type="text" ng-model="foo" typeahead="bar in bars" ng-change="storeLast()">
$scope.storeLast() = function(){
    //Before you reassign oldFoo, you can do some work with it here.
    oldFoo=foo
}
```

However, this feels like a very strange thing to do. I think the better answer would be to redesign what you are trying to do so that you don't need weird code to do it.

Comment: Thanks. I was sure that the typeahead selection triggers ng-change. This looks like a good solution

Comment: @UriKlar Its an ok solution, but I really think you have a bigger underlying problem.